# Change status bar color depending on view controller iOS

Tags: ios, storyboard, statusbar

I have 2 types of view controller view background - black and white. I have tried setting the status bar in Storyboard for each after setting the plist value "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES but it keeps showing the dark colored status bar no matter what.

What's the fix?

iOS8, iphone 5S, Xcode 6

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `preferredStatusBarStyle`to the view controller.
like:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

Where `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` is dark content, for use on light backgrounds and 
 `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` is for light content, for use on dark backgrounds.

You might need to call `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];` in the viewDidLoad to inform the system of a change.